# How to add menu icons to a Facebook Persistent Menu

Tags: facebook, curl, botframework, git-bash, facebook-messenger-bot

How can I add an icon to a Facebook Persistent Menu? As the image below. Using this Facebook example, what I need to add to the code for the Git Bash execution?

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
"persistent_menu":[
{
  "locale":"default",
  "composer_input_disabled":true,
  "call_to_actions":[
    {
      "title":"My Account",
      "type":"nested",
      "call_to_actions":[
        {
          "title":"Pay Bill",
          "type":"postback",
          "payload":"PAYBILL_PAYLOAD"
        }]
    }]  
   },
  {
  "locale":"zh_CN",
  "composer_input_disabled":false
  }
  ]
 }' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?
 access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE"
```

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use facebook emojies -> for example : ✏  ...
And here's a link can help to copy emojies:

https://www.piliapp.com/facebook-symbols/chat/

I mean something like this:

```js
{
  "persistent_menu":[
    {
      "locale":"default",
      "composer_input_disabled":false,
      "call_to_actions":[
        {
          "title": " bla",
          "type":"nested",
          "call_to_actions":[
            {
              "title":" bla",
              "type":"postback",
              "payload":"SeeCourses_PAYLOAD"
            },
            {
              "title":" bla",
              "type":"postback",
              "payload":"SeeMyCourses_PAYLOAD"
            },
        {
          "title":" bla",
          "type":"postback",
          "payload":"SearchForCourses_PAYLOAD"
        }
          ]
        },
        {
          "title":" bla",
          "type":"postback",
          "payload":"SessionsDateAndTimes_PAYLOAD"
        },
        {
          "title":"⚠ bla",
          "type":"postback",
          "payload":"InsituteInfo_PAYLOAD"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "locale":"ar_AR",
      "composer_input_disabled":false,
      "call_to_actions":[
        {
          "type":"postback",
          "title":"Change Language",
          "payload":"Change Language"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: Git Bash doesn't recognize text emojis. Appears a square [] like that.